# How to isolate $A$ in $A\%B=C$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do I solve for *a* in the equation: $a\mod b= c\text{ (same as }a\%b=c$)
Is there an inverse mod, so that I can put the equation in terms of a?

## Thanks in advance!

*b* and *c* can be any real number
I know that $a \mod b =a-\lfloor a/b\rfloor\cdot b$, so I can say $a = c+kb$ (*k* being any whole number), but I was woundering if there is an easier way to write this.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  $a$ and $c$ are numbers that leave the same remainder on division by $b$.  What is there to solve?

Comment: I ask _How to isolate A in A%B=C_, but the content has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a= bm+c$.

$a$ is not unique, for example if $b=2$ and $c=1$, then $a$ is the set of odd integers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.